# Clickable link in e-mail

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

for a web application, when I assign an engineer to a tender he receives an e-mail with some text, the tender ID and a link to the exact tender. If the engineer has an e-mail on gmail, it works perfectly. But if he is on Mozilla Thunderbird the link isn't clickable. My helper method "SendMail" works. I will provide you with the two strings I use (which works perfectly with gmail, but not on Thunderbird)

```
string serverPort = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
string putanjaTenderaLink = "http://" + serverPort + "/tenders?tenders=all&tendtoexpand=" + t.tenderid;
```

Comment: This might be a problem with Thunderbird. Try this [solution](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1159333)

Comment: Maybe make it a html message and create it a real hyperlink?

Comment: @VDWWD hmm, that could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work on Thunderbird, too. This is what worked out for me:

```
    string serverPort = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
    var putanjaTenderaLink = string.Format("<a href=\"http://{0}/tenders? 
    tenders=all&tendtoexpand={1}\">{2}</a>", serverPort, newTender.tenderid, "Tender");
```